# Assistance replacing oracle (+) joins to ANSI joins

Tags: oracle, select, join

I've reviewed other posts as well as Oracle documentation on replacing the older style (+) joins with ANSI format joins.  I'm having a hard time converting this over to what I assume to be two left outer join operations.  My hangup is the two from select statements and where exactly the joins should be placed.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING MODULE,
  NVL(UGA.PERMISSION,AUP.DEFAULT_PERMISSION) PERMISSION
FROM
  (SELECT
    DU.USERNAME,
    A.PROGRAM_ID,
    A.MENU_STRING,
    'Y' DEFAULT_PERMISSION
  FROM
    APPLICATION A,
    DBA_USERS DU
  WHERE 
    A.PROGRAM_ID NOT IN ('.SEPARATOR')
    AND DU.USERNAME NOT LIKE '%#') AUP,
  (SELECT
    USER_ID,
    PROGRAM_ID,
    PERMISSION
  FROM
    USER_PGM_AUTHORITY
  WHERE
    PROGRAM_COMPONENT='PROGRAM') UGA
WHERE
  AUP.USERNAME=UGA.USER_ID(+)
  AND AUP.PROGRAM_ID=UGA.PROGRAM_ID(+)
  AND aup.menu_string = 'Vendor Maintenance'
ORDER BY
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING MODULE,
  NVL(UGA.PERMISSION,AUP.DEFAULT_PERMISSION) PERMISSION
FROM
  (SELECT
    DU.USERNAME,
    A.PROGRAM_ID,
    A.MENU_STRING,
    'Y' DEFAULT_PERMISSION
  FROM
    APPLICATION A,
    DBA_USERS DU
  WHERE 
    A.PROGRAM_ID NOT IN ('.SEPARATOR')
    AND DU.USERNAME NOT LIKE '%#') AUP
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
    USER_ID,
    PROGRAM_ID,
    PERMISSION
  FROM
    USER_PGM_AUTHORITY
  WHERE
    PROGRAM_COMPONENT='PROGRAM') UGA
ON
  AUP.USERNAME=UGA.USER_ID
  AND AUP.PROGRAM_ID=UGA.PROGRAM_ID
WHERE
  aup.menu_string = 'Vendor Maintenance'
ORDER BY
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING;
```

Comment: I would also change `APPLICATION A, DBA_USERS DU` to `APPLICATION A CROSS JOIN DBA_USERS DU`, for consistency and clarity.

Comment: I believe this is perfect.  I was attempting to put the entire join /on statement after the first from and I was getting error saying uga doesn't exist (because it wasn't created yet).  I couldn't find anywhere where the statement was split like that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The join is between `AUP`and `UGA`:

```
SELECT
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING MODULE,
  NVL(UGA.PERMISSION,AUP.DEFAULT_PERMISSION) PERMISSION
FROM
  (SELECT
    DU.USERNAME,
    A.PROGRAM_ID,
    A.MENU_STRING,
    'Y' DEFAULT_PERMISSION
  FROM
    APPLICATION A,
    DBA_USERS DU
  WHERE 
    A.PROGRAM_ID NOT IN ('.SEPARATOR')
    AND DU.USERNAME NOT LIKE '%#') AUP
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
    USER_ID,
    PROGRAM_ID,
    PERMISSION
  FROM
    USER_PGM_AUTHORITY
  WHERE
    PROGRAM_COMPONENT='PROGRAM') UGA
ON AUP.USERNAME=UGA.USER_ID
AND AUP.PROGRAM_ID=UGA.PROGRAM_ID
WHERE aup.menu_string = 'Vendor Maintenance'
ORDER BY
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor it using named sub-queries to make it more readable:

```
WITH AUP AS (                                -- Moved to a named sub-query
  SELECT
    DU.USERNAME,
    A.PROGRAM_ID,
    A.MENU_STRING,
    'Y' DEFAULT_PERMISSION
  FROM
    APPLICATION A
    CROSS JOIN                               -- No apparent join condition so used an explicit CROSS JOIN.
    DBA_USERS DU
  WHERE 
        A.PROGRAM_ID  NOT IN ('.SEPARATOR')
    AND DU.USERNAME   NOT LIKE '%#'
    AND A.MENU_STRING = 'Vendor Maintenance' -- Moved to the appropriate sub-query
),
UGA AS (                                     -- Moved to a named sub-query
  SELECT
    USER_ID,
    PROGRAM_ID,
    PERMISSION
  FROM
    USER_PGM_AUTHORITY
  WHERE
    PROGRAM_COMPONENT='PROGRAM'
)
SELECT
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING MODULE,
  NVL(UGA.PERMISSION,AUP.DEFAULT_PERMISSION) PERMISSION
FROM
  AUP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  UGA
  ON (    AUP.USERNAME  =UGA.USER_ID
      AND AUP.PROGRAM_ID=UGA.PROGRAM_ID )
ORDER BY
  AUP.USERNAME,
  AUP.MENU_STRING;
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing this thread from 10 years ago. I've tried to adapt the solution to my query but I can't figure it out.

Here is my query and I want to replace the (+) with LEFT JOIN

```
FROM a,b,c
WHERE b.a  = '101'
AND a.a    = '202'
AND b.c    = a.c
AND a.d    = c.d(+)
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```